# Basic OCaml function returns type error

Tags: string, types, char, ocaml

I've been trying to run this function :

```
let insert_char s c =
let z = String.create(String.length(s)*2 -1) in 
for i = 0 to String.length(s) - 1 do
    z.[2*i] <- s.[i];
    z.[2*i+1] <- c;
done;
z;;

print_string(insert_char("hello", 'x'));;
```

However the interpreter returns a type error at the last line "type is string * char" and it expected it to be string. I thought my function insert_char created a string. I don't really understand, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your function as a curried function, but you're calling it with a pair of values. You should call it like this:

```
insert_char "hello" 'x'
```

OCaml doesn't require parentheses for a function call. When two values are placed next to each other with nothing between, this is a function call.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of function application in OCaml is `f arg1 arg2`, not `f(arg1, arg2)`. So it would be `print_string (insert_char "hello" 'x')`.

(Once you fix that you'll discover that your code has other problems, but that is unrelated to your question.)